# Google chrome is not launching on behat selenium

Tags: selenium

Whenever I run the selenium test, google chrome is not opening
and i'm having this error Element matching css "#pixelHeader > nav" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)

Comment: Your question is quite vague, so lets see if we can fix that. Do you have the chrome driver installed? Where are you invoking the selenium driver from? What's your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

If the browser does not open, the first element you try to use will fail.  You need to dig into why your browser is not starting up.

The common error I made was forgetting to put the following line into my browser starting method:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "PATH_TO_YOUR_CHROME_DRIVER");
```

Hopefully this is what your missing on that browser start issue. Once your browser is opening, you can dig into your NoSuchElementException issue, if the error persists after the browser opens.